# Replacement for Rhythmbox

Tags: 20.04, rhythmbox, mp3-player

I found Rhythmbox unusable due to incoherent shortcuts.

I would like to replace it with something else for playing local mp3/flac files.

I have spotify already, but the local files options are very limited, and it doesn't support various formats.

Is there any good replacement for rhythmbox?

I would like the replacement to have

- coherent shortcut keys configuration (like play/pause with space bar).
- supports various formats.
- easy to organize the musics.

This is not a duplicate of
[What's a Good Rhythmbox Replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7290/whats-a-good-rhythmbox-replacement)

All the other questions I found are too old and irrelevant.

## Amendment:

1. This is not a duplicate of [What's a Good Rhythmbox Replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7290/whats-a-good-rhythmbox-replacement)

because

a. The accepted answer does not provide me with the alternative to Rhythmbox.
b. I am specifically asking for the 3 requirements I look for in the alternative that are listed above, starting from the functional shortcuts. From the answers to that question, they are not obvious. I believe "try it and see" is not a good answer.

2. I have tried VLC. VLC allows playlists, but not organization of musics in a folder by artists, genre, albums etc...

Comment: Have you already tried VLC Player?

Comment: My two *favorite* choices were already covered in the question you state isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Same as guiverc. Please explain why and how this is not a duplicate of "What's a Good Rhythmbox Replacement"? I would give an answer but it seems like it would simply be an answer for that so . . .

Comment: My favorite mp3 player for years has been covered as well in the answer you didn't accept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a Good Rhythmbox Replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7290/whats-a-good-rhythmbox-replacement)

Comment: FYI:  I'm using *kinetic* (what will be 22.10 on release) and still prefer using two alternatives mentioned in the *duplicate* you claim it's not... I have a GTK & Qt choice (why it's two!), and yes the apps may have changed (the Qt one [`clementine`] was Qt4 in the original duplicate; but it's of course been updated & thus is now Qt5 thus why it still exists in 20.04 & later!, likewise with my GTK choice `audacious`)

Comment: VLC, covers the needs you have and lightweight with added functions. And i like the ability to dock in tray with drop-down controls.  bluetooth headphone is able to skip and pauses tracks without trouble.

Comment: I have tried VLC, but this doesn't manage the music by artists, etc...

Comment: Many players use SPACE BAR to pause/resume music; both my favorites (*covered in the duplicate answer do*), they also sort by artist/have some organization etc, play various types including mp3/flac - I don't see why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: +1 for `Clementine` which is listed in the suggested dupe posted by guiverc.

Comment: @Guiverc
obviously, Rhythmbox doesn't use space bar to pause/resume, VLC does not sort musics by artists, genre. And since none of the answers in the possibly duplicate question does not mention any of the `functionalities` which is asked in this question, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't use `rhythmbox`; but as already stated, my two favorites from the *duplicate* link do everything you want & including using SPACE BAR to pause/play.  `vlc` is I know to some a reasonable (& *lightish* choice), but it isn't mine either.  There are MULTIPLE OPTIONS in the prior example; I've already stated two I like & actually use on my *kinetic* system & I know work on all *supported* releases of Ubuntu too.

Comment: @guiverc Exactly, you answered my question on a comment. Foremost, thank you for that. Second, the functionality you mentioned are not obvious at all from the answers in the linked question, this makes my question unique.
There are [few issues](https://www.google.com/search?q=rhythmbox+keyboard+shortcuts+site:askubuntu.com&sxsrf=ALiCzsYwlo6ISvd9EK_A99wp_ftjCt2Tnw:1655988844769&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinquCWz8P4AhWWhP0HHd1xC-QQrQIoBHoECA0QBQ&biw=1237&bih=714&dpr=1.5) raised on shortcuts on rhythmbox. However, there are no questions which specifically asks for the replacement focusing on this point.

Answer (score 1):

Audacious meets all three requirements.

**Coherent shortcut keys:**

- play/pause = <kbd>spacebar</kbd>
- switch tracks = <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow UP</kbd>/<kbd>Arrow DOWN</kbd>

**Supports various formats:**

> In the default install, the following codecs are supported:
> .
>
> - MP3
> - Ogg Vorbis / Theora
> - AAC and AAC+
> - FLAC
> - ALAC
> - Windows Media (WMA)
> - WAVE

**Ability to sort by artist:**

- Playlist > Sort > By Artist

[image]

---

**Run the following commands to install audacious:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install audacious
```

and there are other packages available with plugins, an ncurses version (command line interface) etc. Just run the following command to list related packages:

```
apt-cache search audacious | grep -i audacious
```

Comment: Personally, my favorite is `vlc -Incurses playlist1.vlc` To create the playlist of all mp3 files, just run `find ~/* -name "*mp3" > playlist1.vlc`